# Prohibit Direct URL for public, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a Rails application. 
When user post content, it makes a folder in public folder. Only admin can put images in it. And user can watch it in folder he made.

But if other users put direct url like this http://railsapp.com/folder/test/test.jpg/, it shows.

I want to prohibit to show when somebody access directly. How should I do?

Do I make the folder in Rails.root? But I don't know how to show it. Please give me a advise.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is pretty obvious - don't upload to `/public` if you don't want it to be public. And no you don't want to change the access rules for your public directory as this will mess up all your assets and the rails fallback error pages.

The common choice is to use `/storage` but then you need to use Rails to serve the assets.

That would involve creating a model and a controller for the uploaded files and serving them with `send_file`.

```
class AttachmentController
  def show
    @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
    # @todo authorize access.
    send_file @attachment.path, type: @attachment.mime, disposition: 'inline'
  end
end
```

A workaround for cases when you don't want to tie up rails threads just with serving images is to use a non guessable hash in the path name to your "private" assets. Note that they are not really private - just harder to find.

Comment: Thx comment max. I'll try to make controller.